# Problem loading a Nib from a UITabBarController

Tags: iphone, uiviewcontroller, uitabbarcontroller, nib

I'm trying to load a Nib from a TabBarController.  I'm doing this by assigning selectedIndex.  The ViewController loaded by index is indicated in the MainWindow.xib where the TabBarController is, assigning the name of the Nib to be loaded in each Tab Bar Item.  Loading works, but if I create an IBOutlet in the ViewController to be loaded and link it to anything (the IBOutlet's object can be of any class) then it crashes in the line where I assign selectedIndex.

Edit>>
I have the application delegate which contains a UITabBarController linked to a UITabBarController object created in MainWindow.xib.

In that UITabBarController object there are some Tab Bar Items each one linked to different UIViewControllers.  These links are established through the property NIB Name.

I'm trying to test the first item linking it to an empty UIViewController, which in this case I called TestViewController (TestViewController.h, TestViewController.m and TestViewController.xib are created).  I wrote TestViewController in the NIB Name property of the first Tab Bar Item.  It works.

Now I put an IBOutlet UILabel in the TestViewController.  I define it like this in the TestViewController.h:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>


@interface TestViewController : UIViewController {
    UILabel *label;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UILabel *label;

@end
```

I then synthesize the label object in the TestViewController.m.  I place a UILabel in the TestViewController.xib.  It still works.

Then I link the label object defined in the TestViewController to the UILabel I created in the NIB file.  I compile and test.  It doesn't work.  It crashes in the part where I assign the selectedIndex to the UITabBarController defined in the application delegate.  The assignation is made like this:

```
self.tabBarController.selectedIndex = 0;
```

I use 0 because I'm testing only with the first Tab Bar Item.  It crashes with SIGABRT signal.

Any ideas why this could be happening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is solved.  I forgot to change the UIViewController linked to the Tab Bar Item to TestViewController.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is significantly improved by the edit. It's hard to say definitively why the crash happens given what you've told us, but I can point you in the right direction.

You've found the line that causes the crash, which is a good start. Place a breakpoint on that line and debug the app. When you hit the breakpoint, look at self.tabBarController. Is it nil? If not, how many objects are in its viewControllers array? If there's one or more, take a look at your TestViewController. Put a breakpoint on its -loadView method, or on UIViewController -loadView. Even if you can't see the source code for -[UIViewController loadView], you can still watch its effect: by the time you get to the end of the method, the view controller's view property should be non-nil.

Also, look in the console after this crash happens. There's usually an error message there telling you roughly why the app crashed.

Comment: thanks.  I think this have given me a hint.  the viewControllers array has no objects.  The UIViewController is not getting into init nor loadView.  I don't why is this, it only happens when I link the IBOutlet to the UILabel.